# Spring-Data-SOLR: Stats result on SimpleQuery won't return me distinct calcs

Tags: java, solr, spring-data-solr

I'm trying to use a `SimpleQuery` to get distinct result from my `solr` collection, but even after setting my `StatsOption` with `calcDistinct` `true`, I can't get the result I want.

BTW I'm using `spring-data-solr-2.1.4.RELEASE`.

SampleCode:

```
Field field = new SimpleField("fieldName");
StatsOptions statsOptions = new StatsOptions().addField(field).setCalcDistinct(true);
SimpleQuery query = new SimpleQuery("*:*").setStatsOptions(statsOptions);
StatsPage<MyClass> statsPage = solrTemplate.queryForStatsPage(query, MyClass.class);
FieldStatsResult statsResult = statsPage.getFieldStatsResult(field);
Collection<Object> distinctValues = statsResult.getDistinctValues();
Set<String> result = distinctValues.stream().map((i) -> i.toString()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
return result;
```

After trying the above code, all I get is the max, min, count, but no results for distinct totals or distinct values.

[image: Result]

What am I doing wrong in this sample?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `disctintValues` collection is also an implementation of `EmptyList` which means that there are no values in the response.

Check if your query returns any result, first.

Comment: I've already tried the same query with stats=on in my solr API and it returns me results for distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

```
StatsOptions statsOptions = new StatsOptions().addField(field).setSelectiveCalcDistinct(true).setCalcDistinct(true);
```

The **processStatsOptions** method in `org.springframework.data.solr.core.DefaultQueryParser` is described as follows :

```
Boolean selectiveCountDistincts = statsOptions.isSelectiveCalcDistincts(field);

if (selectiveCountDistincts != null) {

  solrQuery.add(selectiveCalcDistinctParam, String.valueOf(selectiveCountDistincts.booleanValue()));

}
```